# Action Bar buttons are small

Tags: java, android, button, size, action

I am new to android developpement , and I realized an app which works fine on Samsung Galaxy 2 , and now I am trying to adjust sizes for Galaxy Tab 3 , but i encountred a problem with the buttons in action bar , they are too small . I tried changing their size and putting them in drawable-ldpi but nothing happened , I also added supports-screens to manifest still no luck , and I also created menu-large , but it didn't help

I wish someone could help Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to add images in all drawable folders - `drawable-xxhdpi`, `drawable-xhdpi`, `drawable-hdpi`, `drawable-mdpi`. Android will select the best image according to the screen size.

According to official [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html):

> **You should generate images using the following scale:**
>
> - xhdpi: 2.0
> - hdpi: 1.5
> - mdpi: 1.0 (baseline)
> - ldpi: 0.75
>
> This means that if you generate a 200x200 image for xhdpi devices, you should generate the same resource in 150x150 for hdpi, 100x100 for mdpi, and 75x75 for ldpi devices.